# NHibernate. DTO -> Domain

Tags: nhibernate, dns, poco, dto

I've got SOA which processing data for diff clients(asp,sl). The base of this design is domains of my business model. For transporting,showing it to clients I use DTO. For mapping domain to DTO  I use AutoMapper. Now I should persist new entities from clients. I want use my DTO's at this scenario too. So i've got some questions as I'm not much familiar with this design

1) Is it a good practice build DTO on client and send it to web-service on the wire? MayBe i should pass my domains?

2) Is it possible have several DTO's to one domain (one show at grid, and one to save). For saving  I need set all nonprimitive props at client.

3) DTO -> to Domain. If I've got int can I use AutoMapper to generate NHibernate Proxy for this ID, or I should do i manually.

Your expierence and practice are very interesting. 
Thanks for answer!!!

Answer (score 3):

A good practice to use is screen and command specific DTOs.

An example of this would be when the user is looking at a customer display screen there is a single DTO which contains all (or most if you need to lazy load some stuff) the information for that customer.

The value of this technique is that the data can come from multiple sources which allows you to model your domain as makes sense to you as opposed to how your screens are setup.  It also allows you to change your domain without worrying about your screens as you just need to update the mappings.

Depending on your programming language there may be tools such a [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) (for C#) which allow you to easily create the mappings between domain and DTOs.

Comment: I am new using this architecture: DTO + NHibernate serviceLayer; do you map/copy the version/timestamp from the domain(including child collection) to DTO for concurency purpose?

Comment: If knowing that the domain object has changed is important then yes you would copy it.  That said there are plenty of screens I've worked on where last change wins is a perfectly acceptable strategy.  Warning people that something has changed on EVERY screen will get annoying for your users fast.

Comment: Thanks shane, 1 more question if you don't mind :) 
Related to change/dirty tracking DTO (collection of DTOs) for bulk update/delete/insert from UI grid; Do you have tips/links to resources on how to implement this with NHibernate as CRUD service layer + automapper? I do not want to reinvent the wheel (negative ID for delete flag, new guid for insert + how to update part of domain property from DTO's dirty property only vs update domain property from ALL DTO's property).

Comment: We use CQRS here so for us every change is a different command.  We execute them all in order once the user clicks Save.

Answer (score -1):

Your architecture gets more flexible using DTOs over the wire, in stead of domain model entities. You can have several DTOs per domain.